# Got an error in Nodejs after restarting my computer

Tags: node.js, json

Can someone tell me what is this error about?

```
(node:6540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at global.loadFactions (C:\Users\Brosiden\Desktop\redunion\Server\packages\server\src\systems\factions\index.js:11:29)
    at prom.then (C:\Users\Brosiden\Desktop\redunion\Server\packages\server\src\systems\databox\index.js:29:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:6540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6540) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Everything worked fine last evening. In the morning I rebooted my pc and then it kept throwing this error.

Comment: What's happening in `factions\index.js` line 11?  Show the code in addition to the error.

Comment: `let factions = databox[4].data.factions;` this is line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconcile this:

```
let factions = databox[4].data.factions;
```

With this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

It's basically telling you that `databox[4]` doesn't exist or is undefined.  My psychic powers suggest you have an array called `databox`, but it's length is less than 4.  Either that, or `databox` is not an array, but some other object.

Debug or add console.log statements to print the contents of `databox` before invoking that `factions = databox[4].data.factions` line.

Comment: the problem is that it worked until this morning. but this morning i got some errors regarding mongodb connection and tried to fix them and in the end i had to reinstall mongodb. ill try some other things and maybe i can find a fix

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging it and putting a breakpoint on that line of code?

Comment: i wanted to do that but before that i checked my database and found out it just got deleted so there was nothing to read from it. that array is used to load some things for my gta server. after i uploaded a backup of my database it worked perfectly

Comment: Seeing that the question got closed but I never answered again with how I fixed, there you go. The problem was that the document that held databox array dissapeared from the mongodb database so I had to recreate it from what I remember.